# c# copy structure with condition

Tags: c#

I have a structure with some values `strucPos [] poss;` 
I need to change it, so I create the same structure `structPos[] strpos = poss;`
and make some changes with it. Then I try to copy strpos to poss, but have an error : `object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
poss = null;
while (l < strpos.Length)
{
     if (strpos[l].use != "-")
     {
         poss[poss.Length - 1].count = strpos[poss.Length - 1].count;
         poss[poss.Length - 1].ei = strpos[poss.Length - 1].ei;
         poss[poss.Length - 1].id_r = strpos[poss.Length - 1].id_r;
         poss[poss.Length - 1].nm_p = strpos[poss.Length - 1].nm_p;
     }
     l++;
}
```

As far as I understand it is because `poss` is null. How should I change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple change

```
poss = null
```

to

```
if (strpos.Length > 0)
    poss = new structPos[strpos.Length];
```

And in the looping, you probably wants to use the "l" instead of "poss.Length - 1".

I would do something like this:

```
if (strpos.Length > 0)
{
    poss = new structPos[strpos.Length];
    while (l < strpos.Length)
    {
        poss[l] = new structPos();
        poss[l].use = strpos[l].use;

        if (strpos[l].use != "-")
        {
             poss[l].count = strpos[l].count;
             poss[l].ei = strpos[l].ei;
             poss[l].id_r = strpos[l].id_r;
             poss[l].nm_p = strpos[l].nm_p;
        }

        l++;
    }
}
```

Comment: And, of course, there are other methods to do this :)